# Take user input and continue to use it's variable throughout

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

Not doing anything special. Just taking a user's input between 1 - 500, and then printing the number using for loop for each iteration. It crashes at the for loop. It does not print anything at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int forCounter() {
    int num;
    int count = 0;

    printf("Pick a positive number (1 - 500): ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (num < 1 || num > 500) {
        printf("Out of range, try again (1 - 500): ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    }

    int i = num;

    for (i; count <= i; count++) {
            printf(count);
        }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I take first input applied to 'num' and check if it's above or below allowed amount with the while loop.

When that's done it leaves and should start the for loop with i taking over for num. I tried using num in the place of i but it didn't work so I tried using a separate variable to see if it'd work.

I get two warnings seen in the image provided[Two warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGlXB.png)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to elaborate on the "it didn't work" part? *What* didn't work? Did you get build errors? Crashes? Unexpected results? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `printf(count);` -> `printf("%d ",count);`

Comment: really surprised your compiler didn't throw an error when it saw `printf(count)`

Comment: It just breaks, I added a comment to it stating it breaks during the for loop and does not print out anything.

Comment: squeamish was spot on with his note. I wasn't sure if I needed to add the "%d" and if I did I wasn't sure of where to put it, but this makes plenty of sense now. I added more to add a new line each time, but perfect thank you!

Comment: Breaks *how*? For some example input, what is the expected and actual output? And besides the links in my previous comment, also please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: you also don't need the `i` in the initialisation section of the for loop as it does nothing

Comment: Touche, but I would need to just put it in the initialization of the for loop correct? for (i = num; count <= i; count++) right?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, better? Thanks for the links. I mean it's not perfect but I got the answer as a second comment right after yours so it wasn't terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the format of output in [printf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm).

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

Your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int forCounter(void) {
    int num;
    printf("Pick a positive number (1 - 500): ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (num < 1 || num > 500) {
        printf("Out of range, try again (1 - 500): ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
    } 

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        // printf(count); --> Bad
        printf("Value = %d\n", i);
    }

    getchar();  // this will return immediately
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup thanks. You and squeamish were spot on. I didn't add the Value = part but I did add "%d\n" to it, thanks!